# NodeJS TypeScript - `describe` keyword for mocha throwing error

Tags: node.js, typescript, mocha.js

Hello I am learning Mocha and Chai, so I have installed the following dependencies:
`mocha`, `chai`, `chai-http` and their type definitions.

So I have created a folder: `server.spec.ts` with code below:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import { app } from '../src/server';

//Assertion Style
chai.should();

chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('SIGN UP ENDPOINT', () => {});
```

**So now when I write:**
`describe` I get the following error meanwhile I have installed types for mocha

```
Cannot find name 'describe'. Do you need to install type definitions for a test runner? Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jest` or `npm i --save-dev @types/mocha`.
```

Can I please get help on where I am going wrong

Comment: make sure `@types/mocha` and `@types/chai` are installed

Comment: I did install those types for both ```mocha``` and ```chai```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the typescript config for you tests, there you may need to add the types manually to the type array

```
"types": [
    "mocha",
...
]
```

Comment: Yes, but the one for the tests. You do not want them in the config for the app.

Comment: Still getting the same behaviour